# How can I search multiple files for a single word or phrase using grep and strings?

Tags: linux, search, command

Im trying to look for a word like "numbers" in multiple files not just txt files using terminal. I have tried  strings -r /media/E016-5484/* | grep numbers    But it still doesn't work !

Answer (score 4):

let say you are looking for 1234 in all files which in name contain file_pattern

```
 grep 1234 ` find . -name "*file_pattern*"`
```

or

```
 find  . -name "*file_pattern*" -exec grep 1234 {} \;
```

Comment: Im looking for a patten within the file not the patten of the file name. for example im looking for bob within the text in lots of files. Also I need to have the file path it was found in.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, you are looking for
`grep numbers -r /media/E016-5484`

From the manpage:

> -r, --recursive
>
> Read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only if they are on the command line.  This is equivalent to the -d recurse option.